# RepositoryItemComboBox add specific item for each row

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, row, gridcontrol

I have a RepositoryItemComboBox control on Devexpress GridView and 4 rows. RepositoryItemComboBox.Items.Add affects for all rows. In CustomRowCellEdit and CustomRowCellEditForEditing event I use RepositoryItemComboBox.Items.Clear() and RepositoryItemComboBox.Items.Add but again it affects all rows. I need to modify specific RepositoryItemComboBox. For example in at first row in RepositoryItemComboBox should contains "Michael, John" and at second row in RepositoryItemComboBox should contain "Sarah, Jake".

Answer (score 1):

You can create a repository and assign it based on your condition by handling the [CustomRowCellEdit Event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.CustomRowCellEdit.event).

```
    private RepositoryItemComboBox myRepository(string[] myNames)
    {
        RepositoryItemComboBox repositoryItemCombo = new RepositoryItemComboBox();
        repositoryItemCombo.Items.AddRange(myNames);

        return repositoryItemCombo;
    }
```

Then

```
    private void GridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.FieldName != "YourFieldName")
            return;

        if (e.RowHandle == 1) // Your condition
        {
            e.RepositoryItem = myRepository(new string[] { "Michael", "John" });
        }
        else
        {
            e.RepositoryItem = myRepository(new string[] { "Sarah", "Jake" });
        }
    }
```